# Menu item ID is not recognized

Tags: android, resources, android-menu

menu/activity_main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_save_log"
        android:title="@string/menu_save_log"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
//@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_settings:      // OK
        break;
    case R.id.menu_save_log:      // menu_save_log cannot be resolved or is not a field
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Why menu_save_log is not recognized?

Additional information. R.java:

```
public static final class menu {
    public static final int activity_main=0x7f070000;
}
```

R.java is not updated. Why?

Comment: Have you imported the correct R.java file?

Comment: @Dya: project contains gen/package_name/R.java file, and other IDs from this file are OK (like id.menu_settings). I see that R.java doesn't contain id.menu_save_log.

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: This means that the generated file was not generated as it should, try to clean your project to fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what it could be, but it is quite likely that Eclipse/Android Studio did not yet recognize the new ID. Best thing to do is:

- Make sure your menu file is saved;
- Try rebuilding the project;

In Eclipse:

```
project --> clean...
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to rebuild your project.

Go to Project tab in eclipse and clean the project.

Hope, this will help you.